# AWS S3 - How to serve (and receive) files to/from user based on their geographical location?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

Here's my situation and my goal(s):

I have a SaaS where users (globally) can upload audio files. These audio files are then later streamed (via HTML5 `<audio>`) to potentially anyone in the world. Currently, the only bucket hosting files is in us-west-2, which is obviously problematic when EU customers upload files, and EU users stream audio.

How can I have AWS:

1. Serve up audio files to a user, using the appropriate region based on their geographical location
2. Receive uploads using the S3 bucket (region) closest to the user uploading files

I thought maybe CloudFront would do the trick, but AFAIK, CloudFront requires a file to be downloaded once before it actually caches it, and that won't work for my SaaS. A common use case is that someone in the US might upload an important audio file for someone in Germany to listen to. I would need that person in Germany to experience as fast a streaming experience as possible, and currently I'm getting complaints of slow load times and choppy audio.

S3 cross-region replication might make sense (replicating to eu-central-1 as a good starting point, to cover customers in Scandinavia, other European countries, and the UK), but I'm not sure how to make a single S3 URL pull the file from a specific bucket based on the user's geographical location.

What's the best solution here, and how do I execute it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve file upload performance, you can use [Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html) which enables fast, easy, and secure transfers of files over long distances between your client and an S3 bucket. Transfer Acceleration takes advantage of Amazon CloudFront’s globally distributed edge locations. As the data arrives at an edge location, data is routed to Amazon S3 over an optimized network path.

To improve file download performance, you need to use AWS Cloudfront caching. Since Cloudfront caches content from first request onwards, if you need improve even the first request performance per region, you can automatically populate the cache by requesting the URL timely from different regions.